# How to remove commented lines in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove commented lines in java file.
    For Example: Java file contains below comments

1. //this is java
2. /* I want to remove commented lines */
3. // I am trying
4. /* Revision : 25
       Added this code for some feature */

I used below regular expression to remove comments. This is removing all types of comments
from .java file.

```
string.replaceAll("(\\/\\/.*)|(\\/\\*([\\S\\s]+?)\\*\\/)", "");
```

But i have some specific scenario's where i don't want to delete all comments. 
I'm able to delete all the commented lines(1,2,3 pointed mentioned above) using above pattern.

But I don't want to remove the comment mentioned in 4th point as it contains required information.

Can anyone let me know what is required to change in pattern for not removing such comments?

Note : I know the information, that I should not remove comments contains "Revision : 25"

Comment: I don't think you can remove a `/*...*/` style comment with regex.  It requires a parser.

Comment: @markspace I'm able to remove commented lines using mentioned pattern

Comment: Is it always the first two `/` that you want to remove ? Or are their additional patterns ?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove or ignore other patterns also like /* */ too.

Comment: What if your code contains string which contains such comment? Do you also want to remove it there? Probably not, so regex is not best tool here. You need parser.

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the code. But I want to ignore such comments mentioned in point 4. Could you please let me know which parser is good to use for these type of scenario's?

Comment: Why? The compiler removes them anyway. They don't cost anything except disk space, and a bit of programmer annoyance if they are drivel, in which case the annoyed programmer can remove them.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly @markspace mentioned in his comment, you will not be able in general to remove multi-line comments `/* ... */` using only regular expressions.

This is because regular expressions describes Regular grammar, while multiline `/* ... */` comments can be parsed only by [Context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)-based parser  (because `/*` is always paired with `*/`, such kind of formula is not describable via Regular grammars - it needs stack and therefore corresponds to [Pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)). This issue is similar to [parentheses and square brackets issue.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_nested_parentheses_and_square_brackets)

Furthermore, it could be that `/* ... */` appears inside string constants, so you also have to distinguish these cases, which can be much more complicated.

This is why in order to completely solve this task you will need to write your own grammar and parser. For these purposes I would suggest you learn about [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which is designed for these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the "Revision" info in your regex:

```
(\/\/.*)|(\/\*((?! Revision : \d+)[\S\s]+?)\*\/)
```